# tensorflow_text package installation error in python3

Tags: python, tensorflow, import

I try to install tensorflow_text package in python3. It has been installed successfully. But once I enter it, it cannot run.

```
import tensorflow_text
```

The specific error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Desktop/pythonProject/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow_text
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_text/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow_text.python.ops import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_text/python/ops/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow_text.python.ops.bert_tokenizer import BertTokenizer
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_text/python/ops/bert_tokenizer.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow_text.python.ops.normalize_ops import case_fold_utf8
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_text/python/ops/normalize_ops.py", line 31, in <module>
    gen_normalize_ops = load_library.load_op_library(resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile('_normalize_ops.dylib'))
  File "/Users/xxx/Desktop/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 58, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_text/python/ops/_normalize_ops.dylib, 6): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_text/python/ops/_normalize_ops.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_text/python/ops/_normalize_ops.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

`import tensorflow_text` worked on following setup

```
tensorflow-text-2.6.0
tensorflow<2.7,>=2.6.0
keras~=2.6
keras-preprocessing~=1.1.2
numpy~=1.19.2
protobuf>=3.9.2
```